# The folder of eclipse-plugin in JCDK 3.0.5u1 not found?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javacard

I am new to Java Card development. 
 I want to install the eclipse-plugin for Java Card Classic Development Kit 3.0.5u1 followed by http://blog.csdn.net/chenxu6/article/details/50731125
and download the java_card_kit-classic-3_0_5-u1-win32-do-b35-24_may_2017.msi from
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/downloads/javacard-sdk-2043229.html.

after installed the msi, I can't find the folder **eclipse-plugin** to install the new feature of Java Card.

Anybody can tell me how to do?

Answer (score 1):

The folder is inside **C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Java Card Development Kit 3.0.5u1\eclipse-plugin** by default.

[image]

In your case, if you are not able to find the folder, it is possible that you might have installed the  **.msi** in different folder/drive due to which you are unable to find the same.

Comment: thanks , Anmol Tyagi .the folder I installed is C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Java Card Development Kit 3.0.5u1b,  the difference between yous and mine is b1(the version is not the same), I think that is the miss of Oracle , so cloud you share your .msi for me on cloud disk like google or mega to download. thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

New msi installer file is available now.
'java_card_kit-classic-3_0_5-u1-win32-do-b36-03_jul_2017.msi'

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/downloads/javacard-sdk-2043229.html

This file contains 'eclipse-plugin' directory and files.
You should be able to install with it correctly.

I have installed previous version of msi installer java_card_kit-classic-3_0_5-u1-win32-do-b35-24_may_2017.msi
    then this installer got same result with yours. Actually I could not use this.

I think this problem is relative to msi installer package.

Comment: Thank you very much for your sharing